# How to cast an Object type into a List<Object> type?

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, collections

```
List<Object> frames = new ArrayList();
List<String> names = new ArrayList();

frames.add(names);

//compiler error
frames.get(0).add("ABCD");
```

Since `.get()` returns an object type and an Object type doesn't have `.add()` method the compiler raises an error. How can I cast an object type into a List type?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? Give us more context in case this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Casting is a code smell.

Comment: In your actual situation, are the elements of `frames` all `List<String>`, or does it contain a mix of types and you just know the first one is a `List<String>`?

Comment: @Bohemian, The elements are not the same type.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, i am doing my assignment, code parser that generates all possible paths of a given program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

- Change the `frames` to `List<List<String>>` in case the List `frames` will always contain a List of Strings. It's safe but restricted to a type.

  ```
  List<List<String>> frames = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
  ```
- Use the type casting while getting. This one is not safe and I recommend you to avoid casting whenever possible. Here it would take place checking if the obtained item from the `frames` List is really a List itself:

  ```
  Object first = frames.get(0);
  if (first instanceof List) {
      ((List<String>) first).add("ABCD");
  }
  ```

Moreover, try to avoid raw-types. In this case use the diamond `<>` operators at the declaraion:

```
List<Object> frames = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the generics of the `frames` variable from `Object` to `List<String>`. This way the compiler can see the types which are in the lists, which allows you to use the `get(...)` method.

```
List<List<String>> frames = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

frames.add(names);

frames.get(0).add("ABCD");
```